# Why/How Does BackgroundWorker Work Without DoWorkEventArgs?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

The following is a cut-down version of a class I'm working on (part of a WinForms project):

```
class ReportBuilder {
    private List<Project> projects;
    private List<Invoice> invoices;
    private MyAPI apiObject;

    public ReportBuilder(MyAPI apiAccess, List<Project> selectedProjects){
        this.apiObject = apiAccess;
        this.projects = selectedProjects;
    }

    public void DownloadData(){
        BackgroundWorker workerThread = new BackgroundWorker();
        workerThread.DoWork += (sender, e) => this.retrieveInvoices(this.projects); // yes, the parameter is unnecessary in this case, since the variable is in scope for the method anyway, but I'm doing it for illustrative purposes
        workerThread.RunWorkerCompleted += receiveData;
        workerThread.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void retrieveInvoices(List<Project> filterProjects){
        Notification status;
        if (filterProjects == null){this.invoices = this.apiObject.GetInvoices(out status);}
        else {this.invoices = this.apiObject.GetInvoices(filterProjects, out status);}
    }

    private void receiveData(Object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e){
        // display a save file dialog to the user
        // call a method in another class to create a report in csv format
        // save that csv to file

        // ... ideally, this method would to have access to the 'status' Notification object from retrieveInvoices, but it doesn't (unless I make that an instance variable)
    }
}
```

Now, normally the method signature for the DoWork event handler would be something like this:

```
private void retrieveInvoices(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
```

But, as you can see above, the signature of my retrieveInvoices method doesn't match that. Therefore I expected it to fail (either not compile or just run retrieveInvoices on the UI thread, blocking it, rather than in the background worker). To my surprise it seems to be working, but since none of the BackgroundWorker examples I've seen do this I still think I must be doing something wrong. But am I, and why?

Comment: Yes it does match with this: `(sender, e) =>`

Comment: You could pass `e` to your retrieveInvoices() method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The line :

```
worker.DoWork += (sender, e) => this.retrieveInvoices(this.projects);
```

Introduces a delegate with parameters `(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)` that calls the method `retrieveInvoices` with the parameter `projects`. There's no syntax mismatch.

This is equivalent to :

```
worker.DoWork += (sender, e) => { this.retrieveInvoices(this.projects); }
```

or

```
void doSomething(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    this.retrieveInvoices(this.projects);
}

worker.DoWork += doSomething;
```

To use `retrieveInvoices` as the actual event handler you'd have to write :

```
worker.DoWork += retrieveInvoices;
```

which would cause a mismatch.

BTW BackgroundWorker is obsolete. Anything it does and more can be done using Task.Run, async/await and IProgress. BGW can't be used to combine multiple asynchronous operations for example. The same thing is easy with `async/await, eg :

```
async Task<Report> RunReport(Project[] projects, IProgress<string> progress)
{
    var data= await retrieveInvoices(projects);
    progress.Report("Invoices retrieved");
    var report=await render(data);
    progress.Report("Report rendered");
    await SaveReport(report);
    progress.Report("Report saved");
    return report;
}

//...
Progress<string> progress=new Progress<string>(msg=>statusBar1.Text=msg);

await RunReport(projects);
```

Comment: So, the `(sender, e) =>` bit is turning what comes next into an anonymous method? Even though I don't have curly brackets around the call to retrieveInvoices?

Comment: `(sender,e) =>` is the syntax for a lambda. It doesn't convert what comes next to an anonymous method, it's a method itself. What comes after `=>` is the *body* of the method

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now, thanks.

As for the point about `BackgroundWorker` not combining multiple asynchronous operations, I take it you mean that adding multiple handlers (eg. `worker.DoWork += methodA; worker.DoWork += methodB`) will cause the handlers to be run one after the other rather than in parallel.

Comment: No, I mean that even getting this to work is far too complex - you'd have to use the *completion* handler to start the next BGW passing the first results as state. Then the second completion handler would have to try to start the third one etc. Never mind error handling. In the question I posted though, it's just three `await someAsyncMethod()` calls one after the other